# THREE.LineDashedMaterial - dashes don't work

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I can't get `THREE.LineDashedMaterial` to work correctly in three js (I'm using r73 but have just tried r74 as well).  Changing colours are fine but the dashes don't seem to work.  This is my example:

```
var segmentCount = 200;
var radius = 100;
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 5, dashSize: 1.0, gapSize: 0.5 } ); //new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, linewidth: 10 });

for (var i = 0; i <= segmentCount; i++) {
var theta = (i / segmentCount) * Math.PI * 2;
geometry.vertices.push(
    new THREE.Vector3(
        Math.cos(theta) * radius,
        Math.sin(theta) * radius,
        0));            
}


scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, material));
```

Am I doing something wrong in my example or is this bug (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6699) still an issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are creating a line using `THREE.Geometry` and  `THREE.LineDashedMaterial`, you need to call

```
line.computeLineDistances(); // or lineSegments.computeLineDistances()
```

to get the dashed line to render properly.

three.js r.91

Comment: Fantastic, I can see that in the documentation now.  Thanks for that, I wouldn't have found it for a while :)